# Solving proportions with $3$ ratios,$ x:3:y = -2:3:-4$

Tags: ratio

Proportion seems simple enough for me. Example is $4:x = 2:5,$ and the answer is $x = 10.$

My problem is how do I solve for proportions with $3$ ratios like $x:3:y = -2:3:-4$ ?

Do I write it like

$$\frac{\frac{x}{3}}{y} = \frac{\frac{-2}{3}}{-4} $$
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have: $x:3:y=-2:3:-4$

$\Rightarrow x:3=-2:3$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{x}{3}=-\dfrac{2}{3}$

$\Rightarrow x=-2$

and

$\Rightarrow 3:y=3:-4$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{3}{y}=-\dfrac{3}{4}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{y}{3}=-\dfrac{4}{3}$

$\Rightarrow y=-4$

$\therefore x=-2,y=-4$

Answer (score 8):

Just like chained equalities, you can break it apart.  $x:3:y=-2:3:-4$ becomes $x:3=-2:3$ and $3:y=3:-4$.  Now solve them independently.

Comment: I'll add that you can also use a third proportion, that of $x:y=-2:-4$.  Not that that's helpful in this particular case, but the point is that there are *three* proportions you can extract from such a triple.